# Visual Studio 2022 SQL CLR Project cannot be debugged, Error message "Unable to debug .NET Code. Could not attach to SQL Server process on

Tags: visual-studio, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, remote-debugging, sqlclr

SQL CLR Project in Visual Studio 2022 CE on Windows 10.

Trying to debug a CLR Stored Procedure. Running a test script produces the dialog box error “Unable to debug .NET Code. Could not attach to SQL Server process on . The 32-bit version of the Visual Studio Remote Debugger (MSVSMON.EXE) cannot be used to debug 64-bit processes or 64-bit dumps. Please use the 64-bit edition instead”

There might be a 64-bit edition of the debugger installed, as I have these two separate directories:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x64
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x86

However I cannot work out how to re-configure VS to use the x64 debugger.
I have tried re-configuring the project (using Configuration Manager) to target x64 instead of “AnyCPU”, but the same error persists.

How can I switch to the x64 debugger?

Comment: You can normally only have one MSVSMON.EXE running at the same time so you need to start the x64 version in this case. There is nothing you need to change in Visual Studio as it uses the same type of connection (ie ports) regardless if it connects to the 32- or 64-bit version of MSVSMON on the target server.

Mixing 32/64 is a real challenge during debug so I'd try stick to one or the other.

Comment: Btw, here is some info regarding x64 builds that might be interesting:  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/msbuild-and-64-bit-visual-studio-2022/ and
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-configure-projects-to-target-platforms?view=vs-2022

Comment: @IODEV  "start the x64 version in this case" - indeed, and as the error message says. The question being asked by this post is How?  There does not seem to be any available configuration option to choose between the different editions.  There is some evidence I have seen by way of Googling that VS is supposed to choose which version to use based on the Configuration & Build settings - but my projects are already configured for x64.  Currently downloading VS2019 to determine if VS2022 is currently broken for local sqlclr debugging, which I suspect may be the case.

Comment: On the server, to start the x64 version just use the shortcuts `Remote Debugger Configuration Wizard` and `Remote Debugger` that are installed with VS2022 (which defaults to x64). These shortcuts should be in the start menu and are located in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Visual Studio 2022`. The actuall binaries for both x64, and x86 are located in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 17.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger`.

Comment: Btw, are you using remote deployment or remote attaching? Remote deployment might have some side effects you might have to check up. For example one possible issue is the runtime debugging libraries that sometimes need to be copied by hand to the server.

Comment: EDIT: On the server, to start the x64 version just use the shortcuts Remote Debugger Configuration Wizard and Remote Debugger that are installed using *`Remote Tools for Visual Studio 2022`* ie <https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#remote-tools-for-visual-studio-2022>

Comment: @IODEV  So I think there may be some confusion. Generally with SQLCLR you run a Test Script (T-SQL Script) using the "Execute with Debugger" option. VS then manages everything else behind-the-scenes, including attaching to the (local) SQL Server instance against which you are debugging your CLR assemblies.   So unless the approach to sqlclr debugging has fundamentally changed between VS2019 and VS2022 I am not sure of the relevance of these shortcuts, which in any case I do not have in my Start Menu. Also...

Comment: I have just loaded the same project/solution in to VS2019 and debugging works perfectly. So I think VS2022 is probably broken for SqlClr debug in its current default configuration, bearing in mind this is a very new installation (of both editions). Thanks for your feedback btw

Comment: Great you made it work and god luck with the project! /BR.